# Google chart disappears when changing page in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts

I worked before with google chart and now I using in app rails, but when I change the page and return to chart page he disappears.

Example with images:
https://gist.github.com/joridos/40c4216d30ea689f114a

code:

**application.html.erb:**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi" %>
```

**_administrator_navbar.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to 'Cabuum', root_path, :class => 'navbar-brand header-title' %>
```

**_user.html.erb:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          function drawChart() {

              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Status', 'Quantidade'],
                  ['Pagas',     3],
                  ['Vencidas',      2],
                  ['A vencer',      4]
              ]);

              var paymentdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['label', 'valor'],
                  ['despesas',     1000],
                  ['receitas',     3000]
              ]);

              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
              var paymentchart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('paymentchart'));

              chart.draw(data, {
                  title: 'Relação de Mensalidades'
              });

              paymentchart.draw(paymentdata, {
                  title: 'Fluxo de caixa'
              });
          }
      </script>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="paymentchart" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </div>
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using [Turbolinks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks), you'll have to change your chart drawing js code to something like this:

```
function createChart() {
  // Create chart
}
$(document).ready(createChart);
$(document).on('page:change', createChart)
```